# problem in convert numbers in csv file to int in python

Tags: python, csv

i want to import a csv file to python and convert numbers to int ,
each row has different number (row 1 has 4 grade and row 2 has 10 grade)
when i want to convert number i got bellow error 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
please be informed when i enter equal number in each row problem has been solved .

would you please help me.

my code:

```py
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open ('d:\source.csv') as f :
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        name=row[0]
        these_grades=list()
        for grade in row[1:]:
            these_grades.append(int(grade))
```

csv file :

```
mandana,5,7,3,15
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara,0,5,20,14
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: It looks like your code lost its formatting. Please indent your code by four spaces or select it all and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: Have a look into pandas.  Use this to read your CSV and convert your values to int, as well as run your mean calc.  Additionally, please reformat your question so the code block appears in code format.

Comment: this element is the problem `'', '' `

Comment: @Pygirl--can you give the full line where `'', ''` occurs?  I don't see it.  I don't get an error in running the code and can print out these_grades in the for loop.

Comment: Add the full traceback. It contains further information that may help us help you.

Comment: @DarryIG I tested on my laptop and I was getting these `''`. Check my answer

Comment: Even the error says  so: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` <---

Comment: @Pygirl--strange I don't get that (i.e. I don't get the extra `''` elements).  I copy/pasted the posted data into a text file and is running on an online IDE (repl.it).

Comment: I created a csv file and then texted it.

Comment: I run successfully [as this shows](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/WearableSteepWebpage).  I only added a print statement.  File source.csv created by copy/pasting OP.

Comment: yeah I just checked it on repl.it it's working there but in localhost it's not. I did the same.

Comment: @Pygirl--it also works in Jupyter notebook which runs on my localhost.  Is your csv file created by copy/pasting the data from the OP?  Asking since the data you have in your answer is different from the OP data.  But, possibly this is what the poster has so your answer would solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I did `!touch source.csv` then open it and copy paste the content.

Answer (score 1):

When doing `!cat source.csv` this is the output I get:

```
mandana,5,7,3,15,,,,,,,,,,,
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3,,,,,,,,
sara,0,5,20,14,,,,,,,,,,,
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7,,,
ali,1,9,,,,,,,,,,,,,
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8,,,,,,,
```

The error you are getting because there is `""` present which can't be converted into int.

like for 1st row value is :

```
['mandana', '5', '7', '3', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

You need to get rid of these `''` by using filter:

```
row = list(filter(None, row))
```

**Try:**

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

with open ('source.csv') as f :
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row = list(filter(None, row))
        name=row[0]
        these_grades=list()
        for grade in row[1:]:
            these_grades.append(int(grade))
```

**these_grades:**

```
[0, 16, 16, 13, 19, 2, 17, 8]
```

**edit:**

```
import csv
from statistics import mean

these_grades=list()
with open ('source.csv') as f :
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        grades = list()
        row = list(filter(None, row))
        name=row[0]
        for grade in row[1:]:
            grades.append(int(grade))
        these_grades.append(grades)
```

**these_grades:**

```
[[5, 7, 3, 15],
 [3, 9, 4, 20, 9, 1, 8, 16, 0, 5, 2, 4, 7, 2, 1],
 [19, 10, 19, 6, 8, 14, 3],
 [0, 5, 20, 14],
 [13, 2, 5, 1, 3, 10, 12, 4, 13, 17, 7, 7],
 [1, 9],
 [0, 16, 16, 13, 19, 2, 17, 8]]
```